# Laravel CORS issue for public files

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cors

I am trying to access a log file URL from Angular, but it is showing the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myurl.com/storage/rmlogs/MyFileNameDetail.log' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

All the API requests are working perfectly fine and the error is only for the file requests. I have my files stored inside `rmlogs` directory which is in `storage/app/public/rmlogs` and it is linked to the public folder.

The API codebase is Laravel and the files are stored in `storage` directory. I am able to access the file through browser as well as Postman. As the URL is publicly available, it doesn't need Authentication Token, which I am passing for other API requests.

I have the `cors.php` configuration file as follows:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

and has a `Cors.php` middleware as given below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a typo. It's all `rmlogs`. But it is not working

Comment: you need to allow cros of `http://localhost:4200`  put `'paths' => ['api/*','http://localhost:4200'],`

Comment: Since it's accessing a file rather than a route, I think you may need to add a `.htaccess` in the `rmlogs` folder which adds the CORS headers

Comment: @KamleshPaul — `paths` are which files on the local system to apply the CORS headers to, not the allowed origins.

Answer (score 7):

Via [this blog](https://zaengle.com/blog/configuring-cors-for-laravel-public-storage):

> there are packages available that allow for adding CORS headers to responses sent from a Laravel API. They do so by applying middleware to all of the API’s routes. However, **such middleware is not applied to the public directory**, and that is often the storage location for resources such as user avatar images. Therefore, when those resources are returned to the browser, they do not have the necessary CORS headers applied.

So you need to apply the headers using some other method. This is probably most easily done using your HTTP server's configuration files.

You've tagged this [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) so you can set:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

In your configuration file.

For example:

```
<Location "/storage/rmlogs/">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Location>
```

You could also put the `Header` directive in [a `.htaccess` file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html), but this isn't recommended:

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

If you are on shared hosting, you might not have a choice though.

Comment: Where should I add the `.htaccess` file ? inside `rmlogs` folder ?

Comment: What is the case if i use `php artisan server` ?

Comment: @Quentin I have a similar requirement as in the blog link you provided. I want to use images for canvas.
As of now i am in localhost, i added the header in .htaccess, but i am not able to access images in angular for canvas. I able to drow the canvas using the image, but not able to to use canvas.toDataURL(). (ERROR: Tainted canvases may not be exported) Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing a file in a non-standard storage directory. It might be that your request is not filtered via laravel because it resides in a storage directory, which often permits direct access.

In that case it's handled by the webserver.
These are the storage access rules that get rewritten to the laravel controller in my installation via htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
```

As you can see, `storage/rmlogs` is not part of it, so it's handled by the webserver if i'd try to access a rmlogs directory in storage.

To solve this you could make a .htaccess rule to add it if you run on apache, or a nginx directive if you run nginx.

```
RewriteRule ^storage/rmlogs/.* index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This should be added to the `.htaccess` file inside the `public` folder or to the `rmlogs` ?

Comment: @HappyCoder in your topmost directory, where your index.php file is.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for the solution for apache, here is the ultimate solution according to mozilla's own documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(avifs?|bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|jxl|a?png|svgz?|webp)$">
      SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```